# Flutter Riverpod, build() is not getting called after changing the state

Tags: flutter, riverpod, flutter-riverpod

**Minimal reproducible code:**

```dart
final fooProvider = StateProvider<int>((ref) => 0);

final barProvider = Provider<String>((ref) {
  ref.watch(fooProvider); // 1
  return '';
});

class FooPage extends ConsumerWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: BarPage(),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () => ref.read(fooProvider.notifier).state++, // 2
      ),
    );
  }
}

class BarPage extends ConsumerWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    print('build(BarPage)'); // 3
    final string = ref.watch(barProvider); // 4
    return Text(string);
  }
}
```

<kbd>1</kbd>: `barProvider` is watching `fooProvider`.

<kbd>2</kbd>: I am changing `fooProvider` state.

<kbd>4</kbd>: I am watching `barProvider` (which itself is watching `fooProvider`, see <kbd>1</kbd>)

<kbd>3</kbd>: This should have printed but it didn't.

Comment: The value of barProvider does not change, so a ref.watch is not obligated to trigger a rebuild.  in fact, it shouldn't!

Comment: @RandalSchwartz Yes, the value of `barProvider` didn't change but isn't it listening to the changes in the `fooProvider`?

Comment: the riverpod framework will only cause a rebuild in step 4 if newState != oldState. Since newState is always '', the check returns false, so riverpod will not update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value returned by your provider is always `''`

As such, `Provider` detects that the value exposed did not change, and does not notify listeners.

If you placed a print inside `barProvider`, you would see that the provider got rebuilt.

Answer (score 0):

Following Remi Rousselet's answer,

Try creating a "wrapper" for the String, like so:

```
class Wrapper{
  final String value;
  Wrapper(this.value);
}


final fooProvider = StateProvider<int>((ref) => 0);

final barProvider = Provider<Wrapper>((ref) {
  ref.watch(fooProvider); // 1
  return Wrapper('');
});

class FooPage extends ConsumerWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: BarPage(),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () => ref.read(fooProvider.notifier).state++, // 2
      ),
    );
  }
}

class BarPage extends ConsumerWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    print('build(BarPage)'); // 3
    final string = ref.watch(barProvider); // 4
    return Text(string.value);
  }
}
```

Comment: Your code won't compile. You will also need to change the `Provider<String>` to `Provider<Wrapper>` and then replace the `Text(string)` with `Text(string.value`). In other words, your code just changed my original type from `String` to `Wrapper`.

Comment: Uh, right..I've made edits.